# How can I fix this erroe TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), array([False, False, False, ..., False, False, False]))' is an invalid key?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I m trying to train/test my data using this code :

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matlab.engine
    eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
    feat = tfidfvect
    label = []
    print(label)
    for i in np.arange(1,len(dataset.data)+1).reshape(-1):
    label.append(i)
    print("--------")
    print(label)

    def jFitnessFunction(feat ,label ,X ,x_train, x_test ): 
        if sum(X == 1) == 0:
            cost = inf
        else:
            cost = jwrapperKNN(feat[:,X == 1],label,x_train, x_test)
        return cost

    def jwrapperKNN(sFeat ,label ,x_train, x_test): 
        #---// Parameter setting for k-value of KNN //
        k = 5
        xtrain = sFeat[x_train == 1,:]
        ytrain = label(x_train == 1)
        xvalid = sFeat[x_test == 1,:]
        yvalid = label(x_test == 1)
        Model = fitcknn(xtrain,ytrain,'NumNeighbors',k)
        pred = predict(Model,xvalid)
        num_valid = len(yvalid)
        correct = 0
        for i in np.arange(1,num_valid+1).reshape(-1):
            if yvalid(i)==pred(i):
                correct = correct + 1
                
        Acc = correct / num_valid
        error = 1 - Acc
        return error
        return cost
```

but I keep getting this error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call     last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17344/2041135029.py in <module>
 26 max_Iter = 100
 27 # Binary Grey Wolf Optimization
---> 28 sFeat,Sf,Nf,curve = jBGWO2(feat,label,N,max_Iter,x_train, x_test)
 29 # Plot convergence curve
 30 eng.plt.plot(np.arange(1,max_Iter+1),curve)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17344/2712339248.py in jBGWO2(feat, label, N, max_Iter, x_train, x_test)
 16     fit = np.zeros((1,N))
 17     for i in range(N):
---> 18         fit[i] = fun(feat,label,X[i,:],x_train, x_test)
 19 
 20     fit.sort(reverse=true)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17344/1835931109.py in jFitnessFunction(feat, label, X, x_train, x_test)
 23         cost = inf
 24     else:
---> 25         cost = jwrapperKNN(feat[:,X == 1],label,x_train, x_test)
 26     return cost
 27 
 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
3456             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
3457                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
  -> 3458             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
3459             if is_integer(indexer):
3460                 indexer = [indexer]
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3359             casted_key = self._maybe_cast_indexer(key)
3360             try:
 -> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3362             except KeyError as err:
3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), array([False, False,  True, ...,  True,  True, False]))' is an invalid key
```

I also tried using .loc but I got this

```
attributeerror: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

Comment: Show the actual error, with full traceback.  Don't assume we can guess or deduce which line has the problem.  For that matter, that information might even help you identify the problem.

Comment: Indent the code correctly.  It's hard to read.

Comment: here s the actual error

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this expression (line 25 of your code):

```
feat[:,X == 1]
```

`:` is a `slice(None,None,None)` and the `X==1` is a boolean array (or Series), as explained in the error message:

```
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), array([False, False,  True, ...,  True,  True, False]))' is an invalid key
```

It is raised by `pandas`, and since it talks about a `key`, `feat` must be a DataFrame, where `feat[name]` is used to select a column.  That indexing might work if `feat` was a numpy array, but it is not valid for index a DataFrame.

You don't show the code that calls `jFitnessFunction`, or anything about how `feat` is created.  So I can't trace anything further.